# What can be said about a relation $R=(A,A,R)$ that is refelxive, symmetric and antisymmetric?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

What can be said about a relation $R=(A,A,R)$ that is refelxive, symmetric and antisymmetric?

I know the definitions:

- Reflexive: $xRx$ $\forall$ $x \in A$
- Symmetric: if $\forall a,b \in A, aRb \Rightarrow bRa$
- Antisymmetric: $aRb$ and $bRa \Rightarrow a=b$

Can I get some hints?

Comment: It's just equality.  There are no pairs $a\neq b$ in $A\times A$ such that  $aRb$.

Comment: I have never seen your notation $R=(A,A,R)$. I think you mean $R\subseteq A\times A$.

Comment: Yes, I was about to clarify that, my college has a book and its notation is like that, but it's the same as you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $aRb$ or $bRa$, then $a = b$; this follows since either of $aRb$, $bRa$ implies the other *via* the symmetry condition, and then the antisymmetry condition yields $a = b$.  This in turn implies that $R$ is *transitive*, since $aRb$ and $bRc$ forces $a = b = c$, and  $aRa$ by reflexivity gives us $aRc$, so transitivity follows.  Thus $R$, being reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, satisfies the definition of an equivalence relation.   The equivalence classes are all singletons; thus the assertions "$a = b$" and "$aRb$" are logically equivalent, and $R$ functions for all the world exactly as does $=$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Assume that $aRb$ and use the definition of symmetry and then the definiton of anti-symmetry to deduce an equality.